# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin

class skew_transformed(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

   def _init_(self , skew_cols):
      self.skew_cols = skew_cols

   def fit(self, x, y = None):
      return self

   def transform(self, x):
      x[self.skew_cols] = np.log(x[self.skew_cols] +1)
      return x

skew_obj = skew_transformed()
skew_obj.fit.transform(x.train)
```

i was trying to fix the skewed columns and i was expecting my code to return a transformed columns

error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code snippet you put. First, your syntax for the constructor is not correct, be sure to put 2 underscores on each side

```
def __init__(self, skew_cols):
```

Secondly, in your class you define a fit() method. So to call this method and then (since it returns the instance) to call the transform method (don't forget the parentheses, and the fit function has a non optional unused argument, not sure why you did that), you should do:

```
skew_obj.fit(x=some_value).transform(x_train)
```

Also when creating an instance you don't specify the skew cols, so you should do that as it is again a mandatory argument to set the attribute (it worked probably until now as your constructor syntax was wrong and therefore not recognized).

Also not sure what you need the fit method for.